# websockets in traefik: opening handshake timed out

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to get home-assistant in docker running behind traefik and I think I've had similar issues with other apps using websockets.  The front page loads but when I try to login it just says connecting... and keeps spinning.

I open up the debugger in chrome and see this:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://home-assistant.docker.int.xxx.com/api/websocket' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

If I pass the port through directly to the host (i.e. http://docker.int.xxx.com:8123) it works.

I turned on debug logging in traefik and this is the only relevant message:

```
time="2017-07-08T01:58:18Z" level=debug msg="Writing outgoing Websocket request to target connection: &{Method:GET URL:ws:/api/websocket Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Cache-Control:[no-cache] Connection:[Upgrade] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36] Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.8] Sec-Websocket-Version:[13] Cookie:[__zlcmid=eqgBjgiVtncb4A; _ga=GA1.2.930888288.1496028630] Sec-Websocket-Extensions:[permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Origin:[http://home-assistant.docker.int.xxx.com] Upgrade:[websocket] Sec-Websocket-Key:[FsZu8u+pr9IQDAc3xZYiVQ==] Pragma:[no-cache]] Body:{} GetBody:<nil> ContentLength:0 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:home-assistant.docker.int.xxx.com Form:map[] PostForm:map[] MultipartForm:<nil> Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr:192.168.2.1:49364 RequestURI:/api/websocket TLS:<nil> Cancel:<nil> Response:<nil> ctx:0xc4206ce4c0}"
```

In my home-assistant config I made sure to update the base_url.

```
http:
  # Uncomment this if you are using SSL or running in Docker etc
  base_url: home-assistant.docker.int.xxx.com
```

traefik.toml:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "debug"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https", "ws", "wss"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

InsecureSkipVerify = true

... acme and some manual backends ...

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.int.xxx.com"
```

my docker run.sh:

```
docker run -d --name="home-assistant" \
  --restart=always \
  -v $PWD/config:/config \
  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
  --network=traefik-net \
  -p 8123:8123 \
  --label traefik.port=8123 \
  --label traefik.docker.network=traefik-net \
  homeassistant/home-assistant
```

I have other containers on my traefik-net so I know it's working in general.  I was on v1.3.2 and now v1.3.3 still without any luck.  I've found other posts resolving the issue for nginx, apache, and haproxy, but nothing for traefik.

Comment: I had seen somebody ask if portainer worked through traefik, and it is for me on v1.3.2+.  I tried reverting to v1.2.1 when websockets was originally 'fixed' and interestingly home-assistant now works, but portainer doesn't, so there must be different approaches that don't consistently work.